# ActiveRecord::Base#assign_attributes monkey patch doesn't work after Rails 4 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading an existing Rails 3 upgrade to Rails 4.  This application monkey patches `ActiveRecord::Base#assign_attributes` and was working fine in Rails 3; now in Rails 4 the monkey patched code never gets called.

I have a config initializer which requires the monkey patched code from the lib directory and I can see that it is run once during the startup initialization process.

This is a simplified version of the monkey patch file from the lib directory.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    alias_method :default_assign_attributes, :assign_attributes

    def assign_attributes(new_attributes)
      # Do some custom stuff here
      default_assign_attributes(new_attributes)
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This (and many other) methods were split out into concerns in Rails 4. This one went into `ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment`. You should be monkey-patching that concern, not `ActiveRecord::Base`.

That said, if you want to define your own `assign_attributes` method, you should do so by defining your own concern, **not** by monkey-patching core classes.

Comment: I understand that it has moved out to `ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment`.  This is a module now though so I don't see a clear way to monkey patch this.  I also agree that monkey-patching core classes is a bad idea; that said this is started as a Rail 1 app that is well over 1/2 million lines of code so right now I'm just interested in keeping the existing functionality working and improvements can go in one step at a time.